# Nextjs Image Component 502 Error in Server

Tags: next.js, http-status-code-502, next-images

**next/image** cause the server down of error 502 gateway error.

I check from the devtool network, it go fetch the third party ([themoviedb](https://www.themoviedb.org/)) api. Those images cannot be load correctly but it work fine in my local machine in nextJs build in image component.

I tried to use pure  html tag to load those image, this 502 gateway error is solved.

Is any clue that why **next/image** are causing my DO server 502 gateway error?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, and it was resolved when I reduced the image sizes down to 2000px x 2000px (or below). I also reduced the resolution to 90 at the same time, but I suspect the overall size was the issue. My files were PNGs, in case that's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For production, i installed 'sharp' package which is strongly recommended. Run **yarn add sharp** or **npm i sharp**, and Next.js will use it automatically for Image Optimization.
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/sharp-missing-in-production

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same 502 gateway error with images when deploying a next.js app to AWS EBS (beanstalk). In my case the issue was that the server was under provisioned. Bumping it up to a larger instance size fixed it for me.

(if it helps anyone I moved from a `t4g.nano` to `t4g.micro` instance size)